# Unetstack - Python API - Combined Tx/Rx

Tags: python, unetstack

What would be the most efficient way to transmit a signal, then to switch immediately to RX mode and to record the reflections?

Answer (score 2):

You can transmit a signal using the `TxBasebandSignalReq` message, wait for a `TxFrameNtf` to indicate that the signal was successfully transmitted, and then ask for a recording using a `RecordBasebandSignalReq`. To avoid a gap between the transmission and recording, you can use the `txTime` attribute of the `TxFrameNtf` to trigger the recording (`recTime` attribute). Most modems using UnetStack will allow recordings to begin in the past, as long as the data is in the buffer (usually a few seconds).

The above idea is expressed in the Groovy code snippet below (without any error checking):

```
import org.arl.unet.*
import org.arl.unet.phy.*

def bb = agentForService(Services.BASEBAND)
bb << new TxBasebandSignalReq(signal: mySignal)
def ntf = receive(TxFrameNtf)
bb << new RecordBasebandSignalReq(recTime: ntf.txTime, recLen: nSamples)
```

Here `mySignal` is the signal you want to send (complex baseband representation), and `nSamples` is the number of baseband samples you want to record.

(You can do the same thing using Python in pretty much the same way)

The recording will start at the start of the transmission and will contain the transmitted signal (most likely clipped) followed by any echoes/returns. If you wanted to start the recording at the end of the transmission, you can do so by setting `recTime` to `ntf.txTime + mySignalDuration` where `mySignalDuration` is the length of your signal in microseconds.

Do also bear in mind that the transmitted and recorded signals are complex baseband representations of the signal with a carrier frequency of `bb.carrierFrequency` and sampling rate of `bb.basebandRate`. This representation is more compact than the passband representation. However, if you wanted to use a passband representation in transmission, you can set `fc: 0` in the `TxBasebandSignalReq` and pass in a passband signal sampled at `4*bb.basebandRate`, but you do have to convert the received signal to passband (upsample, multiply by a complex exponential and take the real part). If you're using Python, this is easy to do using something like [`arlpy.signal.bb2pb()`](https://arlpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signal.html).